# Python: Can string formatted with '.format' be multiplied with '*'?

Tags: python, formatting

```
questions = [
"We don't serve strings around here. Are you a string?",
"What is said on Father's Day in the forest?",
"What makes the sound 'Sis! Boom! Bah!'?"
]
answers = [
"An exploding sheep.",
"No, I'm a frayed knot.",
"'Pop!' goes the wessel."
]


print('Q: {}\nA: {}\n'.format(questions[0], answers[0]))
print('Q: {}\nA: {}\n'.format(questions[1], answers[1]))
print('Q: {}\nA: {}\n'.format(questions[2], answers[2]))


print('Q: {}\nA: {}\n' * 3(questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2]))
```

Those two ways to print each of the questions and answers one by one gives same outputs.

But when I tried

```
print('Q: {}\nA: {}\n'.format *3 (questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2]))
```

an exception occured and it says ''int' object is not callable'.

Why didn't it work? Is it just because simply '*' cannot be used with '.format'?

Comment: Putting `*3` between the format function and its arguments does not make sense.

Comment: `format` is a function. Would you expect something like `input*3('message')` to be valid syntax and have a meaning?

Comment: What is the underlaying reason, you want to do that? Because there are simpler ways to print each question and the coresponding answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when I try your second method:

```py
print('Q: {}\nA: {}\n' * 3(questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2]))
```

I get the same `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` error as for the one you point out to be erroneous.

### Cause

In each case, python is reading `3(questions[0], ...)` as a call to the `int` object `3`, which is failing.

### Solution

If however you rearrange the multiplication so that you multiply string by 3, and apply `.format()` to the resulting string you get the desired outcome:

```py
print(('Q: {}\nA: {}\n'*3).format(questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2]))
```

output

```markdown
>>> Q: We don't serve strings around here. Are you a string?
>>> A: An exploding sheep.
>>> Q: What is said on Father's Day in the forest?
>>> A: No, I'm a frayed knot.
>>> Q: What makes the sound 'Sis! Boom! Bah!'?
>>> A: 'Pop!' goes the wessel.
```

#### P.S. Old style formatting

`%` style formatting can b used similarly.  `*` and `%` have the same operator precedence, so first multiplies the string, then does `%`-style formatting.

```py
print("Q: %s\nA: %s\n"*3%(questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2]))
```

Same output as before.

Comment: Sorry, it was 'print('Q: %s\nA: %s\n'*3 % (questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2]))' that I found worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So there, * and % have the same operator precedence, so going left to right, `*` multiplies first, then `%` formats. where as `.format()` as an attribute acts on `3` before the multiplication.  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id15